# Outlook WebAddin(owa) Session is null problem

Tags: session, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I add value to my session object in Outlook web addin
but my different controller session object is null

**Attempted Solutions**

I set the following in my web config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" />
```

I set the following in my web config

```
<remove name="Session" />
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
```

**Other Items I've tried**

1. Made sure  wasn't in the web.config
2. Tried enabling and running with SSL
3. Running in release mode
4. Ensured no Session.Abandon(); or Session.Clear();
5. Made sure no virus scans were running
6. Did a search to make sure I wasn't updating elsewhere
7. Ensured my ASP.NET State Service was running
8. Tried adding in [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
9. I've ensured I have cookies enabled

Comment: Could you please provide more information on what scenario you are trying achieve here using the Add-in?

Comment: I am trying to keep the list of attachments in session

Comment: We are trying to understand if the issue that you are facing is specific to Add-ins. Can you tell us if any Add-in API is not working for you or is giving error?